# Why does Django migration using MSsql suggest success, but fails to create tables?

Tags: sql-server, django

I'm new to Django, and fighting with it by using a non-supported MS_SQL for my DBMS. It's where I have my work experience, but I've been teaching AP Java since the Dot.Bomb ending 2003. Trying to regain some relevance by learning Bootstrap and Django, preparing to one day return to a production environment. (Basically saying I'm not an idiot, but I feel like one as I fight with getting Django to play well with MS_SQL.)
My screenshots below show that I've taken the expected steps:  set up pyodbc for SQL Server, seen "migration" complete successfully, checked SQL Server Profiler to confirm that the dbms received and executed the Create statements,and yet the tables I expected to be created never materialized.  I'm thus far assuming that my migration transaction was rolled back, but if so, I was never informed of such, and instead was mean-spiritedly greeted with pretty "OK" comments.  Grrr!
Any suggestions on where in this pipeline I goofed?
Thank you!

PS: Is there a better way to post summary graphics (screenshots)?  I'd like to follow the site's best practices.

[Versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMMqh.png)

[Results of migration and subsequent attempt to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ5rq.png)

[Footsteps leading up to my wall...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBCH3.jpg)

Comment: How so you've set `AUTOCOMMIT` to `False`?

Comment: Wow.  That's my overuse of copy/paste!  As soon as I set commit to true.....Success!  That confirms that I'm part idiot.  I had tried multiple set-ups, based on searches to solutions several years old, and obviously wasn't thinking. You're the hero; thank you!   Next question though....how do I mark your answer as 'correct'?  I thought I'd see a checkbox.

Comment: Default in Django is True. I asked because maybe you had a reason to set it to False and you have a custom transactions middleware to take care of commits. I'll write an answer and you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your transactions are not committed. You have set `AUTOCOMMIT` setting to `False` in your database settings. Unless you are taking care of commits yourself with custom transactions middleware, you would want to keep this set to `True`, which is also Django default.

Here is a [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/transactions/#managing-autocommit) on this. It states:

> Autocommit is initially turned on. If you turn it off, it’s your
>   responsibility to restore it.
>
> Once you turn autocommit off, you get the default behavior of your
>   database adapter, and Django won’t help you. Although that behavior is
>   specified in PEP 249, implementations of adapters aren’t always
>   consistent with one another. Review the documentation of the adapter
>   you’re using carefully.